# Save button Facebook not showing

Tags: facebook, plugins

I'm trying to add Save button from Facebook on each post at my website
But I got a problem, each post in my website have a button like Facebook, just only when I liked this post, reload page, Save button will appear, if not like, it's empty.

[This thing happen on page get code from Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/save?locale=en_US)

[When I paste link post from my web](https://shareciti.com/2014/04/12/lemon-curd-mousse/)

It's just blank, Why this happen. I tested with any link without my website, it's normal.

[You can try any post link in my website & after paste link to](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/save?locale=en_US)
It's blank.

Please can show me how solve this problem. Thank you